# How to persist custom user control property in application settings?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created simple user control consisting of 3 elements:

2 radio buttons and table layout panel aka Yes or No control.

I created custom property boolean "Value" which changes depending of checked radio button.

UPDATE 1: I added that control to form and bind property "Value" to settings and in control code I added logic to determine which radio but should be checked but after saving settings and reloading form neither of radio buttons are checked.

How can I achieve that effect with the least effort.

Below the code:

```
public partial class YesOrNoControl : UserControl
{
    public YesOrNoControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadValue();
    }

    [Description("Sets the value of Control"), Category("Behavior"), DefaultValue(false), Browsable(true)]
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    void LoadValue()
    {
        if (Value)
        {
            YesButton.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            NoButton.Checked = true;
        }
    }

    private void YesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Value = true;
    }

    private void NoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Value = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define application settings within the IDE (under project settings).
You can then manipulate the settings by use of the [Properties.Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp) namespace.

Settings are automatically loaded at runtime, you can save the settings by calling the Save() method.

More links: [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings)

[Applications Settings for WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/application-settings-for-windows-forms)

Comment: It's not an answer to my question.
I know how to save settings.
My problem is that setting isn't loaded to control. 
I mean neither of radio buttons isn't checked even that property "Value" is saved in application settings.

Comment: According to your code, this is the answer you're looking for.
You're not referencing the application settings anywhere. 

Nowhere in your code is `Value = Properties.Settings.Default.MyControlValue;`
As such, you're not using the application settings.

Comment: Sorry for insufficient explanation to problem. 

I added extra explanation to problem so feel free to become familiar to it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem.
I modified property "Value" to get value from application setting (specially created for this purpose) and set value to same application setting.
At the end of setter I added saving of application settings.
It solves the main problem but it's kind of workaround, not the true answer to problem.
Below the modified code of property:

```
public bool Value
{
    get
    {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.YesOrNoControlValue;
    }
    set
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default["YesOrNoControlValue"] = value;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```